# JQuery: Select at random one <form> from dynamically created array of forms

Tags: jquery

I am having a problem selecting a `<form>` at random, from `<form>`s created dynamically with jQuery, once the `<submit>` button has been clicked.

The code I am trying to use to select a `<form>` and hide all the rest is this (not entirely my own code, assembled from other similar asked on here):

```
$('.submit-button').live('click', function(){
    var result = $("form").get().sort(function(){ 
        return Math.round(Math.random())-0.5;
        }).slice(0,1);

        $(result).appendTo(result[0].parentNode).show();    
});
```

If this helps, this is where I am currently developing the app:
http://yaocho-digital.com/teadecider/

Comment: How well is the code you are trying to use working.

Comment: So far you are selecting a random form, but you aren't hiding the rest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will find all the forms and hide all but a random one:

```
$('.submit-button').live('click', function(){
    var forms = $('form');
    forms.hide()
        .eq(Math.round(Math.random() * forms.length))
        .show();    
});​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/nM8UL/